# Aptana Studio not running anymore on Mac

Tags: eclipse, aptana, macos-big-sur

after updating to Big Sur, Aptana Studio 3 stopped working and the message "no java virtual machine found" was shown. I updated the jre version and now I get an error message related to Eclipse. i tried to install eclipse but i can't solve it. I'm going crazy. please help me. this is the error log that is presented

thanks everybody for support

```
!SESSION 2021-05-10 15:44:23.230 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=unknown
java.version=9.0.4
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=macosx, ARCH=x86_64, WS=cocoa, NL=it_IT
Framework arguments:  -keyring /Users/m.brunetti/.eclipse_keyring
Command-line arguments:  -os macosx -ws cocoa -arch x86_64 -keyring /Users/m.brunetti/.eclipse_keyring

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2021-05-10 15:44:24.465
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.internal_new_GC(Control.java:2176)
    at org.eclipse.swt.graphics.GC.<init>(GC.java:174)
    at org.eclipse.swt.graphics.GC.<init>(GC.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog.initializeDialogUnits(Dialog.java:934)
    at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.TitleAreaDialog.createContents(TitleAreaDialog.java:142)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.create(Window.java:426)
    at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog.create(Dialog.java:1096)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:783)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.ChooseWorkspaceDialog.prompt(ChooseWorkspaceDialog.java:114)
    at com.aptana.rcp.IDEApplication.promptForWorkspace(IDEApplication.java:305)
    at com.aptana.rcp.IDEApplication.checkInstanceLocation(IDEApplication.java:254)
    at com.aptana.rcp.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:112)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:388)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:243)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:653)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:590)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1499)
```

Comment: For Big Sur, a more recent Eclipse version is required. I don't know which Eclipse version your Aptana Studio 3 is based on, but newer Eclipse versions require Java 11 or higher to run, and since you have Java 9, your Eclipse is obviously quite old.

Comment: From their downloads it looks like Aptana is based on Eclipse 4.7, sadly that isn't going to work on macOS 11. The Aptana code needs to be updated to a much more current Eclipse.

Comment: Thanks for you reply. I upgraded Java VM to version 16 but nothing changed.    
eclipse.buildId=unknown
java.version=16.0.1
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=macosx, ARCH=x86_64, WS=cocoa, NL=it_IT
Framework arguments:  -keyring /Users/m.brunetti/.eclipse_keyring
Command-line arguments:  -os macosx -ws cocoa -arch x86_64 -keyring 

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2021-05-11 17:35:51.976